# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `transform'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm making a game in Unity using C# and I want to implement the teleport on key-press mechanic but I'm having some issues with the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport: MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Transform player; 

    void Awake()
    {
        //Find the player object and set it
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Checks if you click the space bar and gets you to -1, 0, 0
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
            transform.position = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

I'd appreciate if you could tell me whats wrong or even improve the mechanic and make it better in any way.

Comment: player.position = transform.position =
i meant this -----
transform.position = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);

Comment: so the error that pops is this: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `transform'

Comment: When do you have the error? when you press space?

Comment: Why do you have two equal signs in same statement?

Answer (score 3):

You're lacking of  `)` here :

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
    player.position = transform.position = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
```

which should be :

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    player.position = transform.position = new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a close bracket `)`:

Here is how to check if a variable is true.

```
if(somthing)
```

Here is how to check if a function is true.

```
if(GetKeyDown())
```

The GetKeyDown function:

```
boo GetKeyDown()
{
    return ...;
}
```

---

```
private Transform player;

void Awake()
{

    //Find the player object and set it
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

void Update()
{

    // Checks if you click the space bar and gets you to -1, 0, 0
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
          transform.position = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You've missed the `l` in 3rd code snippet, should be `bool` :)

Comment: Yeah lol. I shouldn't really matter since that is a pseudo code. The second code is the complete example.